# Nested compound datatypes in HDF5

Tags: c++, c, hdf5

I'm part of a team working on a C++ application that processes various types of messages and outputs them in various formats. For the purposes of this discussion, a message can be thought of as a collection of name-value pairs. The values are typically numeric, but can be strings. The structure of the message is basically being discovered as it is processed. **Messages can be arbitrarily large, so storing a representation in memory is not allowed. A message is processed one name-value pair at a time.** Messages can have internal structure, which is captured by the names in the name-value pairs. A good analogy is to to think of filenames in a directory hierarchy.

I'm working on developing a sub-system that handles these messages and uses the low-level HDF5 API to produce HDF output. Because of the constraints I describe above, the approach that I'm using involves two passes over a message. In the first pass, I gather layout information and build a compound datatype and a dataset. I then make a second pass over the message to write the values out. Because I'm writing **one value out at a time**, I have a sequence like this:

```
 // name, value, dataType, dtSize, ctDataSet and ctSpace have been defined elsewhere 
hid_t valueDT = H5Tcreate(H5T_COMPOUND, dtSize);
herr_t status = H5Tinsert(valueDT, name, 0, dataType);
hid_t filespace = H5Dget_space(ctDataSet);
hsize_t offset[] = { 0 };
hsize_t dim[] = [ 1 };
status = H5Sselect_hyperslab(filespace, H5S_SELECT_SET, offset, NULL,
                                             dim, NULL);
status = H5Dwrite(ctDataSet, valueDT, ctSpace, filespace, H5P_DEFAULT, &value);
```

I've got this working, and I'm now trying to extend it to handle nested compound datatypes. I've got the first pass in shape, but I'm stuck on the second pass. The code in the snippet builds a standalone datatype associated with a value, gives it a name corresponding to an already-existing field in the dataset, and then coaxes HDF5 to write the value out as part of the dataset. **I realize that I wasn't explicit about the name being used. Let's say that we're looking at field *x* in *position*. The name used will be *position.x*.**

I'm puzzled as to how to make that association when the value belongs to an internal compound datatype. Any insights would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create the proper HDF5 datatypes at each nested level, from the bottom first.  Then once you can create the dataset using the total compound datatype and proceed to write data into the file.

I just finished doing something like this, except I was using HDF5 in Common Lisp.  What I ended up doing was defining a type-specification (which sounds like your messages) to describe completely the structure of a data type, and then generated the C-structures using memoization (fancy word for remembering function output).

As an example: Suppose you have the following structure (in pseudocode):

```
Type = {
    x of Xtype;
    y of Ytype;
}
```

You would create the compound datatype for Type by doing

1. Create HDF5 datatype for Xtype (this is recursive and should be memoized)
2. Create HDF5 datatype for Ytype (as is this)
3. Create HDF5 datatype for Type using the HDF5 datatypes for Xtype and Ytype.

This does require that during the first pass you have completely determined the structure of the datatype however, but that doesn't sound like an issue with the way you're doing it.

To extend the example, what you'll need to do is

1. Get the list of data type-specifications of your compound structure.
2. (Recursively) Generate an HDF5 datatype for each type-specification
3. Assemble the total HDF5 compound type from the generated HDF5 datatypes.

## Filling data into the (recursively) compound structure

There are generally two approaches to this.

### Source code generation

You can create code for accessing/filling the structure during the first pass over the data.  This is necessary if you want to write code which knows about C/C++ structures and classes because datatypes are static, so if a type doesn't exist at compile time then it can't exist during run time.  So, you make the type exist during compile time by generating C++ code which you then compile and then run as the second pass.

This approach doesn't sound too promising for what you're doing since it sounds like you'll be processing a fairly large stream of messages, which would require quite a bit of code generation and compiling.  So, on to the next approach:

### Raw binary data access

This approach does away with using static types for structures entirely, which removes the requirement of generating C/C++ compound types.

What you do is use the information you have about what the type of the data should be to compute the total size of the compound datatype and the offsets for where the type members should appear in the memory block for the total type.  This can be done recursively just as the HDF5 type generation.

Example: If you have the compound type

```
Type = {
    x of Xtype;
    y of Ytype;
}
```

you would

1. Get the total size of `Type` by recursively descending into Type's structure, summing the size of `Xtype` and `Ytype` which are found by descending into their structure in the same way.
2. Allocate the size of `Type` bytes in memory.
3. Get the offsets for all of the basic structure elements which will compose the `Type` object.  So if `Xtype` is compound, then you have to get the members of `Xtype`, and if any of those are compound, you get its members, etc.
4. Write each basic structure element into the allocated memory at the appropriate offset.  This has to be done recursively as well since `Xtype` and `Ytype` may be compound types.

This approach works because data is (at least from the programmer's perspective) allocated contiguously, so that `x` and `y` are placed side-by-side inside of the allocated memory.

You are forced to do away with the convenience of having structures/classes in this approach, but this is how the compiler manages structures/classes behind the scenes.

Comment: This sounds promising, but there's something that's eluding me in what you're describing. To be concrete, let's say that in my message, there's a compound type called "position", which has elements called "x", "y" and "z". I've built the overall compound datatype in the first pass. I'm in the second pass, and I'm about to write the value for position/x. Is the datatype I'm going to use a "position" datatype that I've synthesized in your phase 2.2? How does the datatype get associated with its twin in the dataset?

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, the approach you're proposing calls for inserting all message values into the memory dataset and then writing it out. I'm trying to write each value out immediately as it is processed in the second pass. The code snippet I included shows the arrangement I arrived at (with substantial help from the good people on hdf-forum). I've edited the original question to emphasize some of the more troublesome constraints...

Comment: Ah crap now I see what you mean.  I think I point you in the right direction though: Take a look at the source code for the H5TB high-level interface function H5TBwrite_fields_name [H5TB.c](http://www.hdfgroup.org/ftp/HDF5/current/src/unpacked/hl/src/H5TB.c).  This demonstrates how to set just one field in a compound data type, and I'm guessing that this can be done recursively to the member datatypes as well.  This may be what you're doing already in the not-shown code; if so then all I can suggest is to try to use the H5Tinsert function recursively on each field you need to access.

Comment: As a second thought: Do you really want/need to use HDF5 for this?  HDF5 is optimized for large numbers of similar data, e.g. 3-d positions or tables with fixed numbers of fields.  What you're doing sounds more like a tree structure, where each message can have arbitrary structure different from any other message.  I would think that maybe some sort of binary-XML would suit this better than HDF5?

Comment: HDF is actually a pretty fit for what we're trying to do. Even though the messages are different from each other, there are many instances of a given message type in a stream. My existing implementation handles lots of message types as is - the treatment of nested compound datatypes is one of the last hurdles.

Comment: I have no doubt that HDF will work in some fashion, but maybe I'm misunderstanding you.  Do you create a new dataset for each message, or do you append messages with the same structure to datasets with matching structure?

Comment: I do the latter, so writing subsequent instances of a given message involve calling H5Dset_extent with an updated dimension parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up trying a fundamentally different approach than the one I originally described. Rather than trying to map a message onto a **compound datatype**, I create a top-level **group** and for each field in the message I create a **dataset**.  As I process subsequent instances of the message, I change the extents of each of the **datasets**. In situations where a message field is optional, I set an attribute on the **dataset** to identify which of the message instances have values associated with them.

Somewhat to my surprise, the "many datasets" approach results in a larger output file than the "compound dataset" approach, given the same inputs. My naive expectation was that it would be smaller - but I wouldn't be surprised if there are subtleties to using the API that I've missed. There's a more vexing issue, however.  The consumers of the output files will be using **MATLAB** to read them. **MATLAB** does have some high-level functions to read **HDF5** files - in particular **h5read**(). As **h5read**() is implemented, one of its arguments is the name of the **dataset** that you want to extract. I don't really want to ask the users to individually extract every **dataset** that's of potential interest to them. Can anyone think of a reasonable way of wrapping the top-level **group** in a **dataset**?